# How to create a container which allows to retrieve items using index values (e.g. date and name)?

Tags: c++, indexing, struct, containers

How to store the below data in a container such that it is easily accessed by an index? For example how can `Pen` be looked up by specifying the `DATE` and `NAME` values?

```
'DATE', 'NAME', 'ITEM'
'2017-01-01','Kate','Books'
'2017-02-01','Bob','Trousers'
'2017-01-01','Steve','Pen'
```

From my understanding a `struct` or `class` have to be used, below is a struct I have used:

```
struct data {
    std::vector<std::string> date;
    std::vector<std::string> name;
    std::vector<std::string> item;
}
```

How to store and retrieve data using an index?

Comment: Open your C++ book, and turn to the chapter that explains how to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Don't think that your comment is a fair one and is a [perfect example of this](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/572/078/d6d.jpg). I understand those data structures in isolation. The question was about how to create a data container which allows lookups using an index whilst the vectors remain contiguous in memory? Have you worked in the analytic space? If not then perhaps you're not the best person to answer this post.

Comment: A very exhaustive search of the original question was unable to find any part of it that specified the "whilst the vectors remain contiguous in memory" requirement. The only stated requirement was "store the below data in a container". A `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` both meet the requirement of "container", and all the requirements given in the question, since by defining the appropriate key, either `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` will easily locate the "Pen" value, given the lookup "index" of '2017-01-01' and 'Steve'. You cannot expect an answer to a question that was never asked.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `date`, `name` and `item` are all stored in a contiguous format (`std::vectior`). One approach to retrieve the value `Pen` would be to identify the index of `2017-01-01`, then identify the index of `Steve` and then perform a AND operation to identify which indexes both satisfy the condition. This is how analytic workloads are handled and likely due to your lack of experience in this area, you have failed to understand the post. In a similar manner, I understand the workload but fail at the implementation - something you would be strong at.